# Selected value do not changes if default value is selected in select element using angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

After binding data in select element using ng-options , setting selected value from edit function , showing error "Cannot set property 'UID' of undefined" . But if i select another value from select element other than default value , then value changes on edit function.

Here's my select element code:

```
<select name="userRole" id="userRole" ng-model="userRoleModel" ng-options="r.Role for r in roles track by r.UID" class="form-control select-1">
    <option value="" ng-selected="true">ROLES</option>
</select>
```

Angular JS function:

```
**//--Binding data to select element--//**
$scope.GetRoles = function()
{
 $http({
    methhod:"get",
    url:"/Admin/GetRoles",
    datatype:"json"
 }).then(function(response){
    var jData = JSON.parse(response.data);
    $scope.roles = jData.ResultData;
 },function(response){
    console.log(response.data)
 })
};

**//--Edit function--//**
$scope.GetUserUpdateData = function(userData){
$scope.userUID = userData.UID;
$scope.userName = userData.Name;
$scope.userUsername = userData.Username;
$scope.userPassword = userData.Password;
$scope.userRoleModel.UID = userData.RoleID;
$scope.userRoleModel.Role = userData.Role;
$scope.example2model = userData.ChannelUIDs;
}
```

JSON DATA

```
{"ResultData":[{"UID":"1","Role":"Super Admin"},{"UID":"2","Role":"Admin"},{"UID":"2b660a63-c038-4bcd-8fcc-616af7cce4a9","Role":"Operator"},{"UID":"6","Role":"Customer"}]}
```

Rather than this code anything required please comment.

Comment: Use `ng-model="userRoleModel.Role"` or `ng-model="userRoleModel.UID"`

Comment: Same issue , instead it is now not changing value if default value is not selected , inserting blank value on top.

Comment: where is your edit function?

Comment: @Gaurav Srivastava-Edit function is written above its only setting value for now on DOM elements.

Comment: how you are calling GetUserUpdateData function and what is the use of it?

Comment: @Gaurav Srivastava-GetUserUpdateData function is taking data from table row and setting that data to form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the Object from roles as a default value rather than property inside the object. Since default value maps to the object value in ng-options.

```
                <select     
                ng-value="r"
                ng-model="userRoleModel"
                ng-options="r.Role for r in roles track by r.UID" >
                    <option value="?" selected="selected">
                    </option>
                </select>
```

Then in the controller select the default value you need for object.

```
$scope.userRoleModel = $scope.roles[1];
```

Reference : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Where is the `ng-repeat`? I can only see `ng-options`. The issue is more likely that `$scope.userRoleModel` is not defined and causing the error.

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda - It worked but the value is coming from another JSON with different parameter name

Comment: @Ric sorry my mistake. ng-options is the way to go. Only thing is it needs to be mapped to the object rather than the property of the object.

Comment: @Shantnu use a loop to determine the match from the original "roles" and increment your counter till you get the match , once you get the match make it default like $scope.userRoleModel = $scope.roles[count];

Answer (score 1):

You got this error in your edit function because you did not define your `userRoleModel` before assign it's nested property value.

got error for this line `$scope.userRoleModel.UID = userData.RoleID;` because `$scope.userRoleModel` is not `defined`. Declare outside of edit function first as empty object like `$scope.userRoleModel = {}` then should work.

like:

```
$scope.userRoleModel = {}

$scope.GetUserUpdateData = function (userData) {
  $scope.userUID = userData.UID;
  $scope.userName = userData.Name;
  $scope.userUsername = userData.Username;
  $scope.userPassword = userData.Password;
  $scope.userRoleModel.UID = userData.RoleID;
  $scope.userRoleModel.Role = userData.Role;
  $scope.example2model = userData.ChannelUIDs;
}
```

but better to use reference like

```
$scope.userRoleModel = $scope.roles[index];
```

Comment: Thanks @Shaishab Roy it worked but instead of default value one blank value is selected by default

Comment: yes when `userRoleModel` changed from controller then automatically changed in UI as expected

Comment: -then what should i do to get default value

Comment: If you want to show default value in UI then don't need to assign in your controller before select from UI